# matlab-how to draw scatter plot for matrix

Tags: matlab

If my data is:

```
x = [x1;x2;x3;x4;x5];
x = [0.2 0.1 0.1;0.3 0.3 0.4;0.2 0.4 0,4;0.5 0.4 0.6;0.1 0.4 0.3];
```

How to draw a scatter plot for this matrix with PCA style?

Comment: What is "PCA style"?  The only thing I can think of is Principal Component Analysis.

Comment: using the statistics toolbox > http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/princomp.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your question is, but [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot3.html) can be used to 3D scatter plots.

Comment: yes.its principal component analysis.actually x is latent variable.and i try to plot latent variable with pca style plot.its look like scatter plot. for plot3, we need x,y and z right?but i only have x.

Comment: @yana: Your coordinates have 3 dimensions, right?  Then simply take `x(1,:)`, `x(2,:)` and `x(3,:)`.